# Android Google Map : how can I draw a line on Google Map with using the x and y of phone's screen?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline, map-projections

I have a Google Map in my android project. I's set it in specific center and zoom. I disable scroll and zoom. I want to add a line on the specific location of the phone. for example I want to add a line from p1(100,200) to p2(300,400).

problem is that : android use x and y of map (I think, I'm not sure), but I want to use the x and y of my phone screen. How can I fix that?

```
Point p1,p2;
LatLng l1,l2;           
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin,21));
proj = googleMap.getProjection();

p1=new Point(100,200);
l1=proj.fromScreenLocation(p1);
p2=new Point(300,400);
l2=proj.fromScreenLocation(p2);
googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(l1).add(l2).width(10).color(Color.GREEN));
```

Comment: what is your porblem, to get coordinates from screen?

Comment: Android doesn't mean the coordinates of phone, It show the line in that coordinates of the hole Map... I want to show it on the coordinates of the map that is shown.I think I can make it work coorectly but the second problem is that I just want to draw a small line ! but when I darw a line between 100,200 to 101,201 , It draw a big line :| I hope to deliver my purpuse correctly. sorry for my poor English.

Comment: When you call fromScreenLocation - it will reterun coordinates in lat and lng depending on screen coordinates (phone coordinates). 
So, by this coordinates you can draw line, what, actually you did. If your line is too big - change coordinates or line properties. Sorry, but I can't understand your problem, you draw the line, but result is wrong. Why?

Comment: When I call fromScreenLocation, it reffers a point's LatLng that is not in phones visible region... it's out of it(in other place of map)...

Comment: Your word was right. I had mistake. thanks a lot for your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I had this code

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin,21));
proj = googleMap.getProjection();
```

and then when map was zoomed. projection was initialed... because of this, projection had wrong value ...